# jQuery do stuff when a specific key is pressed

Tags: jquery, animation, keydown, arrow-keys

I would like to play the animation "down" when i press down arrow key.

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function(event) {
   $('#down').toggleClass('down');
});
```

Also how can i have it not toggled?

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.keyCode` like following.

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 40) { //40 is the keyCode of down arrow key
        $('#down').toggleClass('down');
    }
});
```